# What is wrong with document.forms[0].submit()?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I am helping someone with a web page that they are having a problem with, I sorted out the validation part but behavior of the submit process is not as you would expect.

To catch and stop the default event, I used the following in the head of the function

```
var evt = event ? event:window.event;
if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
evt.returnValue = false;
evt.cancelBubble = true;
```

If I change any part of it, the prevention of the default action doesn't work and the page in MSIE will submit even when validation errors exist or persist. Under Chrome the browser does not submit but throws an error, with the prevent routine under MSIE the debug show up an error in the same line.

Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

MSIE :  Object doesn't support this property or method

The line in question :

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Trying

```
document.forms.form1.submit();
// or
document.forms['form1'].submit();
```

doesn't work however

```
document.forms.form1.reset();
```

or any of the variants of addressing, including the .getEmelentsById("..."); method works fine, I am just stumped as to the problem, the thought that my JS Interpreter is stuffed up did cross my mind...

Anyone got any ideas that DOES NOT use JQuery please.

Answer (score 1):

Since `form.reset()` does work, but `form.submit()` does not, something is overwriting the `submit` method on the form. I bet you have a form element with an id or name of "submit":

```
<input id="submit" />
```

Or:

```
<input name="submit" />
```

That way `form.submit` would resolve to the input element, rather than the form's `submit()` method.

[Quick jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xoah1Lou/)

The easy fix is to change the id of the element.  The harder, less sensible, fix would be to get a reference to the prototype `submit` method and call it in the context of your form:

```
var f = document.forms.form1;
Object.getPrototypeOf(f).submit.call(f);
```

or

```
document.createElement("form").submit.call(document.forms.form1);
```

Comment: If a web form has to have a submit button and it needs to be a name like submit, type submit, the person I am helping reports that Firefox functions properly and the other browsers MSIE and Chrome don't, I don't understand why all of a sudden a submit method that as far as I can remember back in the mists of time should suddenly be working this way when it has been accepted as the standard name convention in HTML and method in JavaScript

Comment: It doesn't work for me in FireFox - tested via the jsFiddle in my answer.  I don't think that giving a form element a name of "submit" has ever been accepted as the standard naming convention.

Comment: I changed the name of the submit button and that helped with the send, the problem that arose after was that the form wasn't validating before sending in firefox but was in chrome, opera and MSIE. Eventually got it sorted out by adding a submit event listener with a function that used evt.preventDefault(); in it, WTF firefox has to now be the odd ball in the pack IDK.

Since MS has been starting to be sensible, FF appears to have gone off and done its own thing, just wish W3C had some powers to slap Mozilla arond the face to get them to stop messing around.